# Magento Set discount code for specific product on fly

Tags: magento

Thanks in advance..

As in my previous question i have set the discount code for the product on fly its working fine but i want to apply this rule for specific product only is this possible by changing previous code.

please help me...

Thanks,
Jitendra

for your information the code is here....

```
function generateUniqueId($length = null)
    {
        $rndId = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1));
        $rndId = strip_tags(stripslashes($rndId));
        $rndId = str_replace(array(".", "$"),"",$rndId);
        $rndId = strrev(str_replace("/","",$rndId));
            if (!is_null($rndId)){
            return strtoupper(substr($rndId, 0, $length));
            }
        return strtoupper($rndId);
    }
    /* create unique coupan code */

        $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
        $discountprice=$_POST['product']['discountprice']; 
        $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
        $couponCode=generateUniqueId(8);
        $model->setName($couponCode);
        $model->setDescription('Discount coupon for Surger.');
        $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
        $model->setUsesPerCustomer(1);
        $model->setCustomerGroupIds('0,1');
        $model->setIsActive(1);
       // $model->setConditionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:32:\"salesrule/rule_condition_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
        //$model->setActionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:40:\"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
        $model->setStopRulesProcessing(0);
        $model->setIsAdvanced(1);
       // $model->setProductIds($productId);
        $model->setSortOrder('0');
        $model->setSimpleAction('by_percent');
        $model->setDiscountAmount($discountprice);
        $model->setDiscountStep(0);
        $model->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);
        $model->setCouponType(2);
        $model->setCouponCode($couponCode);
        $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
        $model->setTimesUsed(0);
        $model->setIsRss(0);
        $model->setWebsiteIds('1');
        $model->save();
```

---

Here is the perfect code for applying discount to specific product..I found the solution..This code is working fine for applying discount to specific product.

```
function generateUniqueId($length = null)
    {
        $rndId = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1));
        $rndId = strip_tags(stripslashes($rndId));
        $rndId = str_replace(array(".", "$"),"",$rndId);
        $rndId = strrev(str_replace("/","",$rndId));
            if (!is_null($rndId)){
            return strtoupper(substr($rndId, 0, $length));
            }
        return strtoupper($rndId);
    }
    /* create unique coupan code */
        $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
        $sku=$this->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
        $discountprice=$_POST['product']['discountprice']; 
        $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
        $couponCode=generateUniqueId(8);
        $model->setName($couponCode);
        $model->setDescription('Discount coupon for Surger.');
        $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
        $model->setUsesPerCustomer(1);
        $model->setCustomerGroupIds('0,1');
        $model->setIsActive(1);
       // $model->setConditionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:32:\"salesrule/rule_condition_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
        //$model->setActionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:40:\"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
        $model->setStopRulesProcessing(0);
        $model->setIsAdvanced(1);
        $model->setProductIds($productId);
        $model->setSortOrder('0');
        $model->setSimpleAction('by_percent');
        $model->setDiscountAmount($discountprice);
        $model->setDiscountStep(0);
        $model->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);
        $model->setCouponType(2);
        $model->setCouponCode($couponCode);
        $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
        $model->setTimesUsed(0);
        $model->setIsRss(0);
        $model->setWebsiteIds('1');

         $sku=$_POST['product']['sku'];
        print $sku;
/*$skuCond = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
           ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
           ->setAttribute('sku')
           ->setOperator('==')
           ->setValue($sku);
    print_r($skuCond); exit;       
$found = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
         ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
         ->setValue(1)           // 1 == FOUND
         ->setAggregator('all'); // match ALL conditions         

$model->loadPost($found);*/

$conditions = array();
$conditions[1] = array(
'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
'aggregator' => 'all',
'value' => 1,
'new_child' => ''
);
$conditions['1--1'] = array
(
'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found',//-> means 'if all of the following are true' - same rules as above for 'aggregator' and 'value'
//other values for type: 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_subselect' 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine'
'value' => 1,
'aggregator' => 'all',
'new_child' => '',
);

$conditions['1--1--1'] = array
(
'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
'attribute' => 'sku',
'operator' => '==',
'value' => $sku,
);

$model->setData('conditions',$conditions);
$model->loadPost($model->getData());
$model->save();
```

anybody knows how to apply this discount for one product only what happens in following case is that the discount goes to  grand total but i want to apply this discount to that  product which i have entered the discount code can anybody help me to separate this discount.

please help...

thanks,
Jitendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell of the discount system you will need to do the following before saving the rule. As you can see it works by searching for any cart product with a specific SKU.

```
$sku = 'ABCD';            // Put your product SKU here
$found = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
         ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
         ->setValue(1)           // 1 == FOUND
         ->setAggregator('all'); // match ALL conditions
$model->getConditions()->addCondition($found);
$skuCond = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
           ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
           ->setAttribute('sku')
           ->setOperator('==')
           ->setValue($sku);
$found->addCondition($skuCond);
```

Comment: applied it but its not working i mean the execution process of script has stopped

Comment: please help me this  code is not working or i am not applying it properly

Comment: I made a mistake when tidying up the snippet. It seems the order each condition is added in has an effect.

Comment: can u please elaborate more on your last comment.

Comment: My answer has been corrected so it should work better. Please try it again.

Comment: @Jitendra, you should accept the answer (click the check mark next to it) to award clockworkgeek points for providing the correct answer.

Comment: @eyelidlessness FYI i have put this answer my self please read the answer properly..

Comment: @Jitendra, Stack Overflow is a valuable resource partly because its users gain reputation for good questions and answers. It provides a direct way for questioners to accept answers for this reason: the person who provided you the correct answer is rewarded by gaining reputation points and becomes better able to participate in the site by doing so. Taking the answers provided by others and posting it yourself undermines the value of SO for its users.

Comment: @eyelidlessness:Please read the conversation below u'll understand what is going on,and the for the award concern i am ready to accept the question but where is the chekbox to accept it i cant see it after the any answer..

Comment: @eyelidlessness - It seems Jitendra has superseded my suggestion with a better answer. Twice! Thank you for your concern. Still, I had to correct my own snippet in case of another visitor attempting to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer of my own question:

anybody knows how to apply this discount for one product only what happens in following case is that the discount goes to grand total but i want to apply this discount to that product which i have entered the discount code can anybody help me to separate this discount. ???

Thanks,
Jitendra Dhobi

```
 function generateUniqueId($length = null)
        {
            $rndId = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1));
            $rndId = strip_tags(stripslashes($rndId));
            $rndId = str_replace(array(".", "$"),"",$rndId);
            $rndId = strrev(str_replace("/","",$rndId));
                if (!is_null($rndId)){
                return strtoupper(substr($rndId, 0, $length));
                }
            return strtoupper($rndId);
        }
        /* create unique coupan code */
            $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
            $sku=$this->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
            $discountprice=$_POST['product']['discountprice']; 
            $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
            $couponCode=generateUniqueId(8);
            $model->setName($couponCode);
            $model->setDescription('Discount coupon for Surger.');
            $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
            $model->setUsesPerCustomer(1);
            $model->setCustomerGroupIds('0,1');
            $model->setIsActive(1);
           // $model->setConditionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:32:\"salesrule/rule_condition_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
            //$model->setActionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:40:\"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
            $model->setStopRulesProcessing(0);
            $model->setIsAdvanced(1);
            $model->setProductIds($productId);
            $model->setSortOrder('0');
            $model->setSimpleAction('by_percent');
            $model->setDiscountAmount($discountprice);
            $model->setDiscountStep(0);
            $model->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);
            $model->setCouponType(2);
            $model->setCouponCode($couponCode);
            $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
            $model->setTimesUsed(0);
            $model->setIsRss(0);
            $model->setWebsiteIds('1');

             $sku=$_POST['product']['sku'];
            print $sku;
    /*$skuCond = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
               ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
               ->setAttribute('sku')
               ->setOperator('==')
               ->setValue($sku);
        print_r($skuCond); exit;       
    $found = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
             ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
             ->setValue(1)           // 1 == FOUND
             ->setAggregator('all'); // match ALL conditions         

    $model->loadPost($found);*/

    $conditions = array();
    $conditions[1] = array(
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
    'aggregator' => 'all',
    'value' => 1,
    'new_child' => ''
    );
    $conditions['1--1'] = array
    (
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found',//-> means 'if all of the following are true' - same rules as above for 'aggregator' and 'value'
    //other values for type: 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_subselect' 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine'
    'value' => 1,
    'aggregator' => 'all',
    'new_child' => '',
    );

    $conditions['1--1--1'] = array
    (
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
    'attribute' => 'sku',
    'operator' => '==',
    'value' => $sku,
    );

    $actions=array();
    $actions[1]=array(
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine',
    'aggregator' => 'all',
    'value' => 1,
    'new_child' => ''
    );
    //$actions['1--1'] = array
    //(
    //'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found',//-> means 'if all of the following are true' - same rules as above for 'aggregator' and 'value'
    //other values for type: 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_subselect' 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine'
    //'value' => 1,
    //'aggregator' => 'all',
    //'new_child' => '',
    //);
    $actions['1--1'] = array
    (
    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
    'attribute' => 'sku',
    'operator' => '==',
    'value' => $sku,
    );

    //a:7:{s:4:"type";s:40:"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";s:10:"conditions";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:32:"salesrule/rule_condition_product";s:9:"attribute";s:3:"sku";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";s:6:"asdsad";s:18:"is_value_processed";b:0;}}}

    $model->setData('conditions',$conditions);
    $model->setData('actions',$actions);
    $model->loadPost($model->getData());
    $model->save();
```